# Error when executing webpack.config - Can't resolve 'es6-promise'

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, node-modules

When I run this command :

```
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod
```

I get this error:

> ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.browser.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\src\EduSmart\ClientApp'
>        @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts 5:0-95

**When I run this command :**

```
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod
```

> ERROR in dll vendor
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'es6-promise' in 'C:\src\EduSmart'
>        @ dll vendor

I am not sure if these issues are related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first error, run the command with following flag... it should point you to the error:

```
 --display-error-details
```

Seems like just a simple path issue... Make sure package.json paths are ok.

For second error try this:

```
npm install promise-polyfill --save --save-exact
```

Got it from [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1001#issuecomment-302993092) github issue

Comment: I resolved es-6 Promise Issue by manually installing es6-promise but still have other issue. Will update question.

Comment: That is a path issue.... run command with this flag: --display-error-details ....  also, roll back your question to what it was initially for future viewers since my answer now makes no sence. I f anything else comes up, just aask another question :)